# Mac M1 Max `anchor test --skip-local-validator` infinite looop

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-test, solana-test-validator

I'm running solana v1.13.7 locally for solana-test-validator on my Mac M1 Max (13.3).

You can see my left terminal has the local test validator is running on port 8899.

The right side, I am running `anchor test --skip-local-validator`, the test tries deploying the local program but repeats over and over again.

Local video: https://streamable.com/gp6kse
[image: Screenshot from video]

Any pointers?

Running anchor 0.27.0 (via AVM)

```
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120
commit-date: 2022-11-02
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.65.0
LLVM version: 15.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Program deployment works through the TPU port along with the RPC port, so there's probably an issue sending transactions to the TPU port, maybe due to a QUIC / UDP mismatch. The 1.13 tools may be trying to use UDP, which is disabled in 1.14.

This is a shot in the dark, but can you try using Solana 1.14 everywhere, including Solana CLI tools? Anchor 0.27 uses 1.14 internally, so it's better to stay synced everywhere.